# using getline in c++ makes the code run infinetely

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string secret = "abracadabra";
    string password;
    cout << "Enter password:" << endl;
    getline(cin,password);
    if(secret == password)
        cout << "Access granted" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Sorry";
    return 0;
}
```

I tried running the above program, but after entering abracadabra and pressing the enter key the program keeps running,

I figured something is wrong, I used a different ide this time `eclipse`, and it works properly.

Why does the above program work in `eclipse` and not in `netbeans`?

Comment: If you are executing in Running Mode (not debugging) some IDE stop the execution of the program to let the programmer see the output without having to insert pause statement at the end.

Comment: Thanks everyone! but the problem was solved by changing the MinGW setting by doing..... the console type to "standard output"  for running and "external console" for debugging.

Answer (score 4):

Both IDEs will have to hook up the file streams for cin and cout before they start to run program. Evidently netbeans does it differently than eclipse.

To see the natural behaviour, compile your program and start it from the command prompt.

I have not got enough reputation to add comments, but @AMDG's answer presumes that you cannot have spaces or tabs in the password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! but the problem was solved by changing the MinGW setting

rightclick(projec)--->properties 
and then change
..... the console type to "standard output" for running and "external console" for debugging.

Answer (score -1):

You should use that

```
cin >> password;
```

Instead of that :

```
getline(cin, password);
```

And check which compiler you are using in both IDEs.

Comment: Why? The first version will not be able to read spaces whereas the second one will.

Comment: i am using mingw compiler, my program works fine when i use cin>>password; but i want to use getline(cin, password);

Comment: So you're using windows. On windows line separator are `\r\n` Try specify it when you call [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

Answer (score -1):

It appears that getline is waiting for some other delimiter character.
Just to make sure that the delimiter character is a newline character, use

```
getline(cin, password, "\n");
```

Comment: when i try that it gives me a error saying that the candidate expects two arguments, and three were provided.

Comment: Well, that is strange. [Check](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) this out.